# Issue with linear-gradient on when using HSL color definition

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am targeting the latest version of Chrome, I suppose linear-gradient is [compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) even without vendor prefix.

I have notice that when using HSL colors in the gradient definition prefix must be added otherwise it does no render at all.

I would like to know:

- Is this a special case so vendor prefix is a compulsory or it is a browser bug?

```css
#test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  /*works */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 0%, 100%) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 50%, hsl(0, 0%, 0%) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsl(0, 0%, 50%) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0) 100%);
  /* does no work
  background: linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 0%, 100%) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 50%, hsl(0, 0%, 0%) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsl(0, 0%, 50%) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0) 100%);
*/
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: In my case it was not working with background-color, but with background: it worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a bug, you are just using the [outdated gradient syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/#ltlinear-gradient) with the standard property. The old one didn't have the `to` keyword and which was later added. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) page has some history about this change.

Quoting the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients): (note the keyword that I've emphasised)

> The linear gradient syntax is:
>
> <linear-gradient> = linear-gradient(
>       [ [ <angle> | ***to*** <side-or-corner> ] ,]? 
>       <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+
>   )
>
> <side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]

The old syntax worked by specifying the ***origin point*** of the gradient whereas the new syntax works by specifying the ***destination point***, so a value like `top` should be replaced with `to bottom`, `left` with `to right`, `top left` with `to bottom right` etc.

The following snippet which makes the change mentioned above works for me in Chrome v43 and so should work for you in the latest Chrome too.

```css
#test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(0, 0%, 100%) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 50%, hsl(0, 0%, 0%) 100%), linear-gradient(to right, hsl(0, 0%, 50%) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: thanks.. actually I forgot about the new specification.

Comment: I think that you should make more emphasis on the odd fact that the old **top** is translated to **to bottom** ... your applet is correct, but somebody reading it may skip this